# Adjusting hour to account for time difference

Tags: sas

I have an edit check

"If Period = 1,2,3 or 4 and Study Hour = 1 then the Time should be 1 hour plus or minus 15 minutes post-dose of study drug from the same period".These are to be programmed with a +/- 20-minute window of Study Hour 1.00 (relative to their dosing time) It is the protocol window, so even if the event was scheduled not exactly at the 1 hour, we are looking for the deviation window from the 1 hour not the time point of the event. Here is the merged data

[image]

This is my code. I'm getting a lot of flags here so what am I doing wrong?. For context, there is a prothour variable that is 1 but the actual hour time point is 0.77. Should I adjust the 0.77 somehow to account for this?

```
data medfst;
    set dm.ex;
    ptno=strip(compress(clientid,'-'))+0; 
    if ex_stdat=. or ex_sttim=. then delete;
    medday= day;
    rename hour=medhour;

proc sort; 
    by ptno period day medhour;
run;

data medfst; 
    set medfst;
    by ptno period;
    if first.period;
    ex_datetime1=put(ex_stdat,date9.-r)||' '||put(ex_sttim,time8.-l);
    ex_datetime=input(ex_datetime1,datetime20.);

    keep scrid clientid ptno period ex_datetime ex_stdat ex_sttim medhour day;
    format ex_datetime datetime20.;

proc sort; 
 by ptno period day medhour;
run;


data vs;
    set dm.vs;
    ptno=strip(compress(clientid,'-'))+0;
    if VS_TEST in ('SYSTOLIC'); 
    if prothour in ('1');

proc sort nodupkey;
    by ptno period day hour;
run;

data vs1; 
    set vs;

    vs_datetime1=put(vs_dat,date9.-r)||' '||put(vs_tim,time8.-l);
    vs_datetime=input(vs_datetime1,datetime20.);

    keep scrid clientid day hour ptno period vs_dat vs_tim vs_datetime vs_com;      
    format vs_datetime datetime20.;

proc sort; 
 by ptno period day;
run;

data temp;
    merge medfst (in=a) vs1;
    by ptno period;
    if a;
run; 
data final_temp; 
    set temp;
    newhour=hour-medhour;
    datediff=vs_dat-ex_stdat;
    timediff=vs_tim-ex_sttim;
    diff=datediff*24*3600+timediff;

    newdiff=round(diff-newhour*(60*60));
    format diff time8. newdiff time8. timediff time8.;
run;


data final;
    set final_temp;

%inc_subjs;

*****                                                                                               *****;
*********************************************************************************************************;

attrib extra reason length=$5000.;        
*********************************************************************************************************;
*                                     Edit check code and footnote                                      *;
*****                                                                                               *****;



if abs(diff) lt '00:45:00't or abs(diff) gt '01:15:00't then do; 
    reason=trim(reason)||'If Period = 1,2,3 or 4 and Study Hour = 1 then the Time should be 1 hour plus or minus 15 minutes post dose of study drug from the same period#'; 
    extra = trim(extra)||', Hour based on Dose = '||trim(left(medhour))||', Vital Signs hour = '||trim(left(prothour))||', Time deviated = '||trim(put(diff,time8.))||', comment = '||trim(left(vs_com)); 
end;
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of data.  Add actual sample (or example) data with columns only pertinent to the question and code that runs against it.  My take is that image clips of output or error messages is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can round to a nearest multiple using the second argument of [`ROUND`](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.3&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p0tj6cmga7p8qln1ejh6ebevm0c9.htm&locale=en) function.

> **ROUND**(argument <, rounding-unit>)
>
> **Required Argument**
>
> **argument**
>
> - is a numeric constant, variable, or expression to be rounded.
>
> **Optional Argument**
>
> rounding-unit
>
> - is a positive, numeric constant, variable, or expression that specifies the rounding unit.

Round a time value to the nearest hour (time is seconds, hour is 3600 seconds)

```
closest_hour = ROUND(mytime, 3600);
```

Round hour (number) to nearest hour (time value)

```
closest_hour = ROUND(myhour*3600, 3600);
```

and of course, round hour (number) to nearest whole hour (number)

```
closest_hr = ROUND(myhour);  * default rounding unit is 1;
```